# Simple way to place a label at the top corner of bokeh streaming plots as a python oscilloscope

Tags: bokeh, python-3.7

I want to place a label at the top left corner of each streaming plot, be it one plot, or two plots, etc. The plots are stretched in both directions. For now, I have to manually specify a y postion depending on how many plots are shown. (y=200 for two plots, and y=440 for one plot) One may resolve it by recording the total range of y values shown in the plot, but it feels too hacky. I'm wondering if there is a simple way to do this. Thanks for any help.

[image][image]

```
from bokeh.server.server import Server
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, Label
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.layouts import column
import numpy as np
import datetime as dt
from functools import partial
import time


def f_random():
    data = np.random.rand()
    data = (dt.datetime.now(), data)
    return data


def f_sinewave():
    data = np.sin(time.time()/1.)
    data = (dt.datetime.now(), data)
    return data


def make_document(doc, functions, labels):
    def update():
        for index, func in enumerate(functions):
            data = func()
            sources[index].stream(new_data=dict(time=[data[0]], data=[data[1]]), rollover=1000)
            annotations[index].text = f'{data[1]: .3f}'

    sources = [ColumnDataSource(dict(time=[], data=[])) for _ in range(len(functions))]
    figs = []
    annotations = []
    for i in range(len(functions)):
        figs.append(figure(x_axis_type='datetime', plot_width=800, plot_height=400, y_axis_label=labels[i]))
        figs[i].line(x='time', y='data', source=sources[i])
        annotations.append(Label(x=10, y=200, text='', text_font_size='20px', text_color='black',
                                 x_units='screen', y_units='screen', background_fill_color='white'))
        figs[i].add_layout(annotations[i])

    doc.add_root(column([fig for fig in figs], sizing_mode='stretch_both'))
    doc.add_periodic_callback(callback=update, period_milliseconds=100)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # list of functions and labels to feed into the scope
    functions = [f_random, f_sinewave]
    labels = ['random', 'sinewave']

    server = Server({'/': partial(make_document, functions=functions, labels=labels)})
    server.start()
    server.io_loop.add_callback(server.show, "/")
    try:
        server.io_loop.start()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print('keyboard interruption')
```

Answer (score 1):

For now you could do:

```py
Label(x=10, y=figs[i].plot_height-30, ...)
```

It seems like allowing negative values to implicitly position against the "opposite" side would be a nice feature (and a good first task for new contributors), so I would encourage you to file a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues) about it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Unfortunately, I just realized, with your method, the position in y direction is depending on the zoom level of the browser. I guess it is really a issue I have to report. I would probably go with the matlibplot route, where one can specify the relative x,y position by using a percentage of the size of the frame like [here](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.annotate.html).

Comment: That's a little surprising but in any case OSS moves forward through collaboration and feedback from users, so an issue would certainly be appreciated.